# The container should run a web server that serves static pages from /var/www/website on the host system (not inside the Docker container itself)

Tags: docker

I am learning Docker and would like to know the steps to implement the below scenario. Please help

The container should run a web server that serves static pages from /var/www/website on the host system (not inside the Docker container itself)

Answer (score 1):

Docker cannot automatically access file on the host machine. You need to mount **/var/www/website** into the container, so that docker can access it. Use the -v option when running the container:
 `-v /var/www/website:/var/www/website`

Once you do that, /var/www/website folder inside the container will be the same as the one on your machine.